# Parse message in Log Insight

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

I want to parse this message :

> [2021-08-30T14:01:01.443908+00:00] technical.INFO: Webhook
> "239dfb55-c8f3-4ae2-8974-22dadb7417ba" (wallet.create) has been
> handle.

To have :

UUID (here : ***239dfb55-c8f3-4ae2-8974-22dadb7417ba***)

The words in brackets (here: ***wallet.create***)

I can get the UUID but not the terms in brackets.

I think my regex is correct but, it doesn't work on Log Insight :(

My query :

```
fields @message
| filter @message like /technical.INFO: Webhook "/
| parse @message /(?<webhookId>\b[0-9a-f]{8}\b-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-\b[0-9a-f]{12}\b)/
| parse @message /(?<@endpt_get>\(([^)]+)\)/
| sort @timestamp desc
| limit 5
```

My regex for word in brackets :

https://regex101.com/r/ewSm6O/1

If i comment this line of my query :

```
parse @message /(?<@endpt_get>\(([^)]+)\)/
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Db2r2.png)

I have the good result

The line of code I commented above blocks the result, I return nothing.

Could you please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your log messages are all going to have this same format, you can use glob instead of regex (and for something complex like this, that may be easier)

```
fields @message, @timestamp
| parse @message "technical.INFO: Webhook \"*\" (*) has been handle" as uuid, term_to_catch
| sort @timestamp by desc
| display @timestamp, uuid, term_to_catch
```

if some of the sections of the message (like technical.INFO ) would change, you can always * them and put a dummy variable to catch but then do nothing with it

```
| parse @message "*: Webhook \"*\" (*) has been handle" as type, uuid, term_to_catch
| display @timestamp, uuid, term_to_catch
```

alternatively - if you insist on your regex - then the reason is most likely because you are not storing the parsed results as their own variable, and so they are overwriting each other

```
| parse @message /your*regex/ as uuid
| parse @message /your*second.regex/ as term_to_catch
```

may get what you need as well.

Comment: Thank's a lot @lynkfox :)